# characterization of lightly mixing

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, mixing

In Friedman and King's book "Rank one lightly mixing" and in Wenyu Chen's paper "the notion of mixing and rank one examples", the authors recall the definition of a **lightly mixing** transformation T:

for all $A,B$ of positive measure, $\liminf_{n\to \infty} \mu(T^{-n}A\cap B)>0$.

They suggest an equivalent characterization where it suffices to take $A=B$:

for all $A$ of positive measure, $\liminf_{n\to \infty} \mu(T^{-n}A\cap A)>0$.

I couldn't find how this characterization can be equivalent to the definition. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Have a look at Lemma 4.2 in the paper. Is that what you mean? If not, where is the claim that it suffices to consider "for all $A$ of positive measure, $\liminf_{n\to \infty} \mu(T^{-n}A\cap A)>0$"?

Comment: My question is indeed about Lemma 4.2 in "the notion of mixing and rank one examples" where the author uses this characterization. Also in "Rank one lightly mixing"(p.282) the authors state this equivalent characterization and use it in Lemma 2.4. I know the equivalence holds if the map is ergodic, but I don't know how it could hold if the map is only measure preserving as stated in these Lemmas.

Comment: @user747652 how do you know the equivalence if the map is ergodic? also, the two statements are obviously not equivalent if you only know the map is measure-preserving. just take two disjoint mixing measure systems; then the second condition holds but the first doesn't.